# Get all contacts Google API via C#

Tags: c#, google-contacts-api

I want to get all my contacts via a Windows Form application.

I understand I can use something like this:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        new[] { ????? },
                        "user", 
                        CancellationToken.None, 
                        new FileDataStore("Contacts.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

exactly as in the [example for the books API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth), or "drive" API:

```
        credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                           GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                           new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive,
                           DriveService.Scope.DriveFile },
                           "user", CancellationToken.None, 
                           new FileDataStore("Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;
```

But my question is what should be on the ??? (since I could not find the .Net Contacts Library [here](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/)

Where is the `google.apis.contacts*` assembly?

Answer (score 1):

I think the missing library you're looking for is this: https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/

It's all the GData API's in one library (of which the Contacts API is one).

Comment: yes, I have the one also installed. However ... does GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker works with this one? Or does GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker <> google-gdata ?

Comment: I think it cant be used and I need to resort to https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs